# How to load all dependency on mavenhub.com

Tags: maven

I want to user this jar package, but there are a lot of dependencies - so, how can i load these jars?
http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/com.force.sdk/force-jpa/22.0.6-BETA#depMaven

Comment: What problem? Just add this artifact as dependency to your `pom.xml` and Maven download all this dependencies automatically.

Comment: I don't know maven - how it works?, what i have to do with the pom.xml?

Comment: I've added simple instruction about how to download all dependencies. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you read docs about Maven. You may start from [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). Following instructions from this tutorial create simple application:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After that in current directory Maven creates `my-app` directory where you can find sample `pom.xml` file.

Open it and correct `dependencies` node:

- delete `junit`:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

- add force:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.force.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>force-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>22.0.6-BETA</version>
  </dependency>
```

After that in `my-app` run command `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`. Maven download all dependencies and place it under `target/dependency` directory. For example I have the following JAR list:

```
$ ls -1 target/dependency
asm-3.3.1.jar
datanucleus-core-2.2.3.jar
datanucleus-enhancer-2.1.0-release.jar
datanucleus-jpa-2.1.7.jar
force-connector-22.0.6-BETA.jar
force-jpa-22.0.6-BETA.jar
force-metadata-api-22.0.0.jar
force-partner-api-22.0.0.jar
force-wsc-22.0.0.jar
geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
gson-1.7.1.jar
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
js-1.7R2.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
transaction-api-1.1.jar
```

Now you may do anything with these JARs.